# Data cleaning in Pandas, where the csv file has all data of each row in 1 field

Tags: data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have really messy data that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see all the data in each row is contained in 1 column separated by a semi colon.

How do I arrange this data so that they are spread out over more columns? For example, `category_id`, `category_id_lvl_0` etc., to be in separate columns and the rows underneath corresponding to that columns i.e ones that are separated by the semi colon to fall under the column of `category_id`, `category_id_lvl_0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That to me doesn't seem like messy data at all, it is just a csv file with a `;` delimiter. Depending on the region settings excel can use different delimiters when saving data as `.csv` file, `;` being one of them. By default `pandas` assumes a `,` as the delimiter, which in this case does not apply. Try reading it in by specifying the correct delimiter using the [`sep` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=";")
```